# ssis package excecution error

Tags: ssis, msbi

I created a package which is used to transfer data from oracle instance to SQL instance 
I got following errors

1.[SRC WKF_LOG_HISTORY [63]] Error: Either Table Name or SqlCommand property should be set.

2.[SSIS.Pipeline] Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PRIMEOUTPUTFAILED.  The PrimeOutput method on SRC WKF_LOG_HISTORY returned error code 0x80004005.  The component returned a failure code when the pipeline engine called PrimeOutput(). The meaning of the failure code is defined by the component, but the error is fatal and the pipeline stopped executing.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.

3.Task DFT Copy Data failed could any one please help to get out from these.

thank you

Comment: "Either TableName or SqlCommand property should be set" So. On your Oracle Source connection, is either the table name or SQL command set?

Comment: nope this is the first!

Comment: Post a screenshot of the properties of SRC WKF_LOG_HISTORY.